# Freshly installed elementary OS Freya missing in boot menu

Tags: system-installation, boot

I just installed elementary OS Freya in a partition where the old elementary OS Luna used to be, but in grub I can't see the option to boot with Freya, but the old Luna one. When selecting this one the computer restarts again.

The grub partition already existed because I have Ubuntu. I chose `/dev/sda8` as the partition were elementary OS would be installed, but I wasn't really sure about this one. It's the same partition I chose for elementary to be installed.

So why is it missing in grub?

Comment: Have you tried updating the GRUB from your Ubuntu partition using `update-grub`?

Comment: ummm nope? Would that help my situation?

Comment: It will make GRUB automatically refresh its list of entries and possibly fix the issue you're having. Try it and let me know how it went.

Comment: that totally worked! thanks! I assumed with the new installation it'd be automatically included to the boot load menu

Comment: @r3bl you should post your solution as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grub currently shows the old list of operating systems installed (hence the Luna boot option instead of Freya).

To show the updated list of entries, you have to refresh GRUB from the Ubuntu installation (or a Ubuntu Live Media) with the command `update-grub`.

(*Thanks [@r3bl](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/138/r3bl) !*)